# Insert linearlayout in tablerow

Tags: android

I want to add linearlayout in table row and that linear layout will hold some buttons and textview.How I can achieve that.I am using this but it does not display anything

```
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
final CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
checkbox.setPadding(10, 5, 0, 0);
checkbox.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 15);
checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Hello");
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 14);
tv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
checkbox.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(tr.getContext());
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
linearLayout.addView(checkbox, new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.addView(tv, new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tr.addView(linearLayout);
table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start you need to close your curly braces at right place. While Setting onClickListener, you are not closing the curly brace and not even putting a semicolon there. So it seems you are making a textView in the listener. The following line

```
checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

should be like this

```
checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    protected void onClick(View v){
        //your listener code here.
    }
});
```

And when the layout is so complex, you should use XML files instead of Dynamically coding, unless you have to.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.Actually the number of row in table is not fixed.So that's why I am trying this by coding.If you have any better idea then please share with me.Thanks for the response.

Comment: You can make a single table Rows in XML and can just inflate it for each row in code.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding row params like this

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);


row.addView(linearLayout,  new TableRow.LayoutParams(1));
```

Add relativeLayout instead of linearlayout and set params like this for textview

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rel_lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
tv.setLayoutParams(rel_lp);
```

Comment: If it worked than please correct the answer. For that you have to take relative layout and set it properties. I have edited my answer